# Why clipboard.setdataobject doesn't copy object to the clipboard in C#

Tags: c#, clipboard, copy-paste, keystroke

I have a win app (C#) that use clipboard to send and receive data to/from other applications. for example I want to use Word app in windows, I copy a text using c# to the clipboard, but when i want to simulate paste key `(Stroke Ctrl+v)` in c# , the clipboard is empty and i just got `"v"` as result.
To copy to the clipboard i use the following code:

```
  public static void CopyToClipboard(string textForCopyToClipBoard)
  {
     Clipboard.Clear();
     Clipboard.SetDataObject(
     textForCopyToClipBoard, 
     true, 
     5, 
     200); 
   }
```

To simulate paste or stroke Ctrl+v, i use the following code

```
public static void PasteFromClipboard()
   {
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^v");
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well , The Correct Code About The Putting Objects On Clipboard is:

```
Clipboard.SetText("hello");
```

You'll need to use the `System.Windows.Forms` or `System.Windows` namespaces for that.

You can only access the clipboard from an STA thread. Rick Brewster ran into this with some refactoring of the regular Edit->Paste command, in Paint.NET.

Code:

```
IDataObject idat = null;
Exception threadEx = null;
Thread staThread = new Thread(
    delegate ()
    {
        try
        {
            idat = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        }

        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            threadEx = ex;            
        }
    });
staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
staThread.Start();
staThread.Join();
// at this point either you have clipboard data or an exception
```