# How to store a text that is saved in clipboard and paste into the url address bar?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

Having a hard time figuring this out,

**Use Case**: On the UI, I am clicking on a Copy button which is saving a specific URL to the clipboard, I need to figure out a way to paste this clipboard URL to the URL address to navigate to.

Would I need to save the clipboard URL to a text string then driver.Navigate(text) or can i skip this process and just somehow paste the clipboard text to the URL Address bar?

Note: This is a selenium webdriver C# environment

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaK92.png)

Comment: Use driver.get or driver.navigate.  You can't paste into the location bar using Selenium.  You could execute javascript which would set the location bar, but you'd still need to read data from the clipboard using c#.  (Most browsers will prompt when javascript tries to access the clipboard.)

Comment: string myURL = Clipboard.GetText();
Console.WriteLine(myURL);
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("window.open('" + myURL +"');");
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(myURL);

Comment: ^ this is what i've used so far, the javascript is opening a new tab but not pasting the myURL into the address bar. not even sure if Clipboard.GetText() has any value

Comment: I am sure the url might be specified as one of the attribute for `Copy` button. I would recommend get the url by using element `.getAttribute` method and then you can use `driver.Navigate(url)`. Can you please share the html of the `Copy` button.

Comment: unfortunately the Copy button element doesnt contain the URL since it is dynamic, but here is the html for the Copy button************ <div class="formPublish--Website-Button" data-bind="css: { 'formPublish--Website-Button-Inactive' : Parent.CanCopyForm() === false }, click: GetHostedForm">Copy</div>********

Comment: not sure why you are opening a new window, but the driver would need to be switched to that.  Why not use driver.get on the current window?  Javascript that opens a new window without an event can sometimes be blocked.

Comment: I was able to find the solution to saving the text from clipboard from this post, Thanks for the help guys! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421985/why-clipboard-setdataobject-doesnt-copy-object-to-the-clipboard-in-c-sharp